# How can I add Link in footer CKAN 2.8.1 app?

Tags: ckan

I want to add a link in the footer of CKAN app. I can't locate the footer file.
Please provide inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Please, checkout customizing [ckan templates documentation](http://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/theming/templates.html#replacing-a-default-template-file). Footer file is located in [ckan/templates/footer.html](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/master/ckan/templates/footer.html)